# Connect to sqlite database on win IOT

Tags: sqlite, raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I'm getting error {SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: Could not open database file: C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\Documents\Storage.db (CannotOpen) when trying to connect to sqllite database on a raspberry pi 3, with WIN IOT is the OS. I'm using the SQLite.Net-PCL ver 3.1.1 implementation of SQLite.

```
var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);    var fileName2 = "Storage.db";
var path2 = Path.Combine(documentsPath, fileName2);     

try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path2))
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string m_er = ex.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use UWP application. On Windows IoT Core you can use [FolderPermissions tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/commandlineutils#set-folder-permissions-for-uwp-apps) to make this path "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\Documents" accessible to a UWP app.

```
FolderPermissions C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\Documents -e
```

Since you don't receive "access denied" error so I suppose you have already added the following capability in the Package.appxmanifest.

```
<uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary" />
```

Then your code will work. (I test on Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows IoT Core version 10.0.17763.107)

[image]

Comment: Setting the permission on the folder "C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\Documents" fixed the problem. Thanks very Much!

Comment: I added line; md.CreateTable<RaspTables.Category>(); after the md= new line and received error; SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: disk I/O error. I've checked and the storage.db and storage.db-journal both have read write permissions. I see that it's been suggested to set the flags for the database, QLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex, but I don't see how to do that?

Comment: Hi @Dave, it seems the "can not open" issue has solved, right? If it is true you can reference ["Help Center > Answering"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so we can complete this issue. And I see you have post a [new question of the issue about CreateTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348519/how-to-add-tags-to-sqlite-connection) so we will continue there.

Comment: Yes this issue is closed. Thanks again.